# Apache cordova apps in Visual Studio 2015 requires internet connection?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

There is an option to develop Cordova HTML5 apps in Visual Studio 2015 Community Version. When I select the option, I'm asked to install the missing feature. Does this require an internet connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont have the Apache Cordova tools installed you will need an internet connection to get them